# Struts2 java.sql.Timestamp to Calendar type conversion

Tags: struts2, timestamp, typeconverter

In an Struts 2 Action class, there is `List<Object[]>` object. One of the elements of each Object array is `java.sql.Timestamp`, which I display using `<s:date>` Struts tag. Can I convert data from `Timestamp` to UTC calendar using application level conversion? I tried using a custom converter and added following line into `xwork-conversion.properties`:

```
java.sql.Timestamp=com.test.CalendarConverter
```

But, this did not affect the output and the `convertToString` method of `CalendarConverter` was not even called. Below is the `CalendarConverter`

```
public class CalendarConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CalendarConverter.class);
String format = null;

public CalendarConverter() {
    format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
}

public Object convertFromString(Map context, String [] values, Class toClass) {
    Calendar cal = null;
    logger.debug("-----------------> In convertFromString: value[0]- " + ((values == null || values.length < 1) ? "NULL" : values[0]));
    if (values != null && values.length == 1) {
        if (values[0].trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                tz = userSession.getTimeZone();
                if (tz == null) {
                    tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                }
                DateFormat dateFormat = null; 
                if (isValidDate(values[0], format)) {
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                }
                dateFormat.setLenient(false);
                dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
                Date dt = dateFormat.parse(values[0]);
                cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
                cal.setTime(dt);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Error in date conversion");
                logger.debug(ex.getMessage());
                //throw new TypeConversionException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

    return cal;
}

public boolean isValidDate(String str, String format) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    df.setLenient(false);
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    df.parse(str, pos);
    if (pos.getErrorIndex() == -1 && pos.getIndex() == str.length() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
    String data = null;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
    tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    if (tz == null) {
        tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    }
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);
    logger.debug("-----------------> In convertToString: o- " + o + " (" + (o == null ? null : o.getClass().getName()) + ")");

    if (o != null) {
        if (o instanceof Calendar) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar)o;
            data = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        } else if (o instanceof Date) {
            data = dateFormat.format((Date)o);
        } else if (o instanceof Timestamp) {
            data = dateFormat.format((Timestamp)o);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you put your `xwork-conversion.properties`? Is your `CalendarConverter` constructor being called?

Comment: Do you have errors? What did you do to make call to your converter? Why do you think it should be called? Do you know what is a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: @AleksandrM xwork-conversion.properties at classes level (web-inf\classes). CalendarConverter gets called alright, when the underlying object is java.util.Calendar.

Comment: @RomanC : I don't get any errors or Exception. It seems like the convertToString function is not getting called when the object is of type java.sql.Timestamp.

It works fine, if the object is of type java.util.Calendar

Comment: Post the code for action class.